# How to use the delete operator in a callback function (Question of Understanding)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a question about the delete operator.

Is the first option dangerous to delete the attribute before setting the attribute to null?

Sorry this is really just an understanding question and I would be happy if someone can explain it to me.

Option 1:

```
var requestPool = context.get('requestPool');

requestPool.pool[id].to = setTimeout(function() { 
    delete requestPool.pool[id];
}, msg.modbusJob.timeout);
```

Option 2:

```
requestPool.pool[id].to = setTimeout(function() { 
    requestPool.pool[id].to = null;
    if(requestPool.pool[id]) {
        delete requestPool.pool[id];
    }
}, msg.modbusJob.timeout);
```

Comment: there should be no difference (unless someone overwrite `to` with setter/proxy)

Comment: If `requestPool.pool[id].to = null;` does not fail with an exception, the `if` test will always succeed.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. If you're deleting it then why set it to `null`? And why set it back again? And why is a timeout reference called `to`?

Comment: have you actually tried to run this code? Please post a working example after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just remember that there is generally zero reason to use the `delete` operator, and that often it actually hurts performance quite a lot due to invalidating JIT assumptions, so as a protip: not using `delete` is almost always the correct choice.

Comment: Do you understand that all `delete` does it remove a property from an object (it doesn't free memory).  So, there is NO reason to `delete` a property and then immediately set it back again - in fact it's even bad for performance.  You may as well just set it to `null` in the first place if that's the end state you want it to be in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the first option dangerous to delete the attribute before setting the attribute to null?

It is safe to use `delete` on a property before setting it to `null` but it is also unnecessary. I'm guessing (but I could be wrong) that you are trying to make sure the previous item is garbage collected. If so, you don't need to `delete` it as well. Either one will make the previous item garbage-collectible (assuming there's not some other piece of code somewhere holding on to a reference to it).

Answer (score 0):

> Is the first option dangerous to delete the attribute before setting
> the attribute to null?

I would write it like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    if(requestPool && requestPool.pool && requestPool.pool[id]) {
        delete requestPool.pool[id];
    }
}, msg.modbusJob.timeout);
```

Or with more modern syntax:

```
setTimeout(() => { 
    if(requestPool?.pool && requestPool.pool[id]) {
        delete requestPool.pool[id];
    }
}, msg.modbusJob.timeout);
```